# php com ms word Documents->Open() not working

Tags: php, com, ms-word

I'm generating MS Word .docx files with COM (Component Object Model) using Find/Replace method on a template document.

The problem: it works fine on my PC, but I can't get it work on the production PC!! I have same configuration on both computers.

First I instantiate a COM object `$word = new COM('word.application'); 
echo "Loaded Word, version {$word->Version}\n";` says 12.0. So I deduce everything is ok so far.
Something goes wrong on `$word->Documents->Open("c:\\test.docx");` command. It look's like whatever I put between the brackets is not passed through. Just the same as I'd put `$word->Documents->Open(" ");`

On the next line: `$word->Selection->Find->ClearFormatting();` I get the error message: 
"Trying to get property of non-object " and a fatal error after that. It looks like an empty string is passed in `Documents->Open()` and the COM object is destroyed.

I tried relative, absolute paths, backslashes, double slashes... and it look's like it doesn't have anything to do with it.
As well the command `$word->visible = 1;` doesn't bring word up.

There is more or less the same configuration on both PCs :
1st PC: - win7 Ultimate,32-bit, ms Word 7, same WAMP version
2nd PC: - win7 Professional,32-bit, ms Word 7, same WAMP version

I tried macros on the second PC, like: Documents.Open FileName:="test.docx" etc. and it works fine. I have no idea what is different on the second PC and what could possibly be the cause.

Comment: try this: $word = new COM("word.application") or die("Unable to instanciate Word"); ....maybe the word.aplication doesn exist in you production or is in another path

Comment: Word isn't designed to run in a server environment.  I strongly suggest you change your solution to something that's a bit more robust.  For example, [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb735940(v=office.12).aspx) is a document describing how to generate documents using OpenXML directly, without involving Word.  Or, for that matter, try [PHPDocX](http://www.phpdocx.com/).

Comment: Thank you for your help. Robert, the statement $word->Version returns Word 12.0. But why $word->visible = 1 doesn't bring it up?